# Is it acceptable to leave my job as a trainee in order to go to graduate school?

Tags: professionalism

I am currently a IT trainee at a multinational company. 
I joined the company when I was finishing my Bachelor's degree and got myself a 6 month contract that has the chance to be extended up to 12 months. 
I am now planing to leave said company after my contract is over (even if I get offered a permanent job) in order to get my Master's degree. 
The company I'm working at is currently undergoing budget cuts and can't offer external training to employees (which makes it hard to obtain certifications that are offered easily at similar companies to employees with the same skills that I have) and the chances to progress with my career here are pretty slim.

I'm not sure if it is considered unacceptable to leave a job that could be permanent in order to pursue a higher degree in my field of studies. I don't want to be perceived as a snob because I want to expand my horizons, but I'm not sure how I can explain the situation to my manager.

Comment: Unless you agree to the new contact you can leave the day your contract is over. You don't have to give a reason simply don't agree to the new contract.  At the end of the day your 6 months at this company will only be made public to another company if you choose to place it on your resume.  If you feel the experience at the company cannot improve your work history leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is acceptable! In my very humble opinion, your career and frankly your life is about developing your skills as a professional and as a person. Were you at a financially stable place that was offering to further your formal education, as some companies will, then I would say to really think about why it is you do not want to pursue your education through your employer. But, as that does not seem to be the case, simply put: **You gotta do you**!

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not sure if it is considered unacceptable...

Unacceptable to whom?  You don't have "permanent record" following you around from job to job.

Do whatever you feel is best for you.  **Do not treat business relationships as if they are personal relationships.**  You accepted a contract.  It's ending.  Your obligation is done.  Your employer would have no regrets if they decided not to renew the contract, and neither should you.